# Image button in vertical left menu bar in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, css, user-interface

I have a requirement to have a Vertical left Menu bar, with `Image button` in it. I googled but could only find `href` link to use. Could anyone guide on how to achieve this?

Sample code that I've with `href` is below. Is there a way I can use Imagebutton in Menu.

```
<div class="arrowlistmenu">
    <h3 class="menuheader expandable">Dashboard</h3>
    <ul class="categoryitems">
        <li><a href="URL"  target="_blank">Customer Driven Metrics</a></li>  
        <li><a href="URL" target="_blank">Change Condition Patrol</a></li> 
    </ul>
</div>
```

I tried the link http://www.obout.com/ which is good for many controls including Menu list but again, there is a `URL` option but not any `Image button` option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not enitrely sure I understand what you want to achive, but from what I got you have an input field with `type="image"` that you want to link somewhere.
If this is the case you can add `onclick` to your input element.

e.g.

```
<input src="image.jpg" type="image" onclick="location.href='http://google.com';">
```